# Why is there white space at the bottom of my web page when run in the browser?

Tags: html, css

When I run my code in the browser, I have this little line of white space at the bottom of the page. I’ve been trying different solutions but can’t seem to find one that works. Below is the home.html page. Maybe someone here can shed some light into the problem.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="keywords" content="cooper, scooper, dog, pop, pick, up>
<meta name="author" content="primarysnail">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<meta name="description" content="connecting clients in need of dog pick pick up srvice with scoopers who will come to the client and scoop the poop">
<title>CoopersScoopers || Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/style.css">
</head>

<body> 
  <header>   <!-- company name top left; nav bar top right -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="branding">
        <h1><a href="../pages/home.html"><span>cooper</span>Scoopers</a></h1>
      </div>  
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li class="current"><a href="../pages/home.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="../pages/contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="../pages/find.html">Find a Scooper</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section class="showcase"> <!-- showcase section; button to find scooper (./find.html) -->
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Leave the</h1>
      <br>
      <h1>Poo to the</h1>
      <br>
      <h1>Professionals.</h1>
      <button type="button"><a href="../pages/find.html">Connect With a Scooper Today</a></button>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="info-bar"> <!-- info bar; shows scooper process in 3 sections -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="box">
        <img src="../images/poop.jpg">
        <h3>Connect With a Local Scooper</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <img src="../images/location.jpg">
        <h3>Mark Your Poo</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <img src="../images/calendar.jpg">
        <h3>Schedule Future Scoops</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="testimonials">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Come Experience the Joy of a Poop-Free Life.</h1>
  </section>
</body>
<footer>
  <p>Copyright &copy; primarySnail//</p>
</footer>
</html>
```

Here is the linked style.css file:

```
body {
 font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 1.5;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}

/* global */

.container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
button {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ffff00;
  opacity: 0.8;
  border: none;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: -20px;
  float: right;
}
button a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4b0082;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
}

/* header */

header {
  padding-top: 30px;
  min-height: 70px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #f0e68c;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #8a2be2;
  font-size: 10px;
 }
 header a {
   text-decoration: none;
 }
nav a {  
  color: #8a2be2;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 10px;
}
header span {
 font-size: 15px;
}
header li {
 float: left;
 display: inline;
 padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}
.branding {
  float: left;
}
.branding h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  border: 4px solid #8a2be2;

}

header nav {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
header .current {
 border: 1px solid #999;
 background-color: #8a2be2;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
header .current a {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* showcase */

.showcase {
  background-color: #8a2be2;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: left;
  min-height: 200px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #f0e68c;

}
.showcase h1 {
  font-size: 55px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* info bar*/

.info-bar {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #f0e68c;
}
.info-bar .box {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.info-bar .box img {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
}

/* testimonials */

.testimonials {
  background-color: #8a2be2;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.testimonials h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

/* footer */

footer {
  background-color: #f0e68c;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why that little line of white space is in there at the very bottom. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UgB1.png)

Comment: That whitespace is shown due to the scrollbar at the bottom

Comment: Can u put a link to codepen or something?

Comment: @MahabubulHasan hi, could you explain more? I don’t understand

Comment: Okay, just checked the code on Codepen and i can't seem to find the white space as it appears on the image you sent. So i suggest you use your dev tools to inspect and see what's actually there.

Comment: just tested on chrome, there's no white space.. i suggest you to add this property " html{
  overflow-x: hidden;} " to your css and refresh your browser

Comment: it simply removes the horizontal scroll bar from your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I have observed white space showing in the bottom. It is because the elements inside body tag is not occupying the full available body size.

[image]

elemets heights are as 
 body- 722
 header- 104
.showcase- 251`enter code here`
.info-bar- 201
.testimonials- ~71
 footer- ~62

the white space in the botom is remaining area of viewport. If you make the browser smaller the white space will go away.

To fix this proble you can use below css to the body.

```
body {
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe;
font-size: 15px;
line-height: 1.5;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
background-color: #ffffff;
/* Add below lines*/
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: stretch;
```

}